# formatting is not being kept using php include

Tags: php, css, formatting

I have this website where I include by using php db data. Those are feedbackcomments on a feedbackpage.
I have this:

```
<?php include 'writetosite.php'; ?>
```

Now somehow the standard formatting is being overruled on this section.
Then I put a paragraph tag around it. Now only the last post/comment gets the desired formatting.
But I want all posts/comments to have this formatting.

This is how it looks now: http://frontline-tours.com/front20/comments_db.php

This would be the include file:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE Controle = 'ok' ORDER BY id DESC");


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{ echo " 
       ".$row['Country'].",
       ".date('l \t\h\e jS \o\f F Y', strtotime($row['Date'])).",<br/><br/>
       ".$row['Comment']."<br/><br/>
       ".$row['Name']."
       <br/><br><hr>";}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Insufficient details provided, consider to contribute some more details and explain neatly :) also, if you have a `<style>` block in that include file, it will have higher preference, in this case, either you need to have specific selectors, or override

Comment: I doubt that it is the php include itself that causes it to stop working.

Comment: solved! thanks anyways